# Queuing a function amongst Jquery animation

Tags: jquery, function, delay

Hi I am trying to create an layered image effect but I am having trouble queueing a function along with jquery animation.

Basically I need to hide all of my .bar divs then execute the function after which will make them fadeIn one at a time. I need to do it this way as there will be multiple images and this effect will be what creates the transition between them.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="image">
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css is like this

```
.container {width:700px;height:400px;margin:0 auto;background:#FF0;}
.image {background:green; width:700px; height:300px; }
.bar { height:300px; width:50px; background:orange; float:left;}
```

and the javascript/jquery is like this

```
$(function(){

var i = -1;

function fading(){
    function fader(){
    setTimeout(function () {          
          i++;                    
          if (i < 15) {          
             $('.bar:eq(' + i + ')').fadeIn('200');
             fader();           
          }                       
       }, 100)
    }
    fader()
}

$('input').click(function(){

    $('.bar').hide().queue(function(){
                    fading()
                    $('this').dequeue();
                    });
});


});
```

If anyone has ideas on how this can be done differently or achieved in the way I have laydd out that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the animation queue in this way because your `.queue` call is getting mixed in with all the `fadeIn()` calls and won't wait until after those as they are using the animation queue also.  You could create some separate queue and use that, but that is probably not worth it.

Why not just have the `fader()` function trigger your next action when it finishes with the 15 layers?

Or, you can pass a callback function into `fader()` which it can call when it's done with the 15 layers?

I don't get exactly what you're trying to do, but you can kick off another function in here when you're done fading in the 15 layers (see where I added the `else`):

```
function fading() {
    var cntr = -1;
    function fader() {
       setTimeout(function () {          
          cntr++;
          if (cntr < 15) {          
             $('.bar:eq(' + cntr + ')').fadeIn('200');
             fader();           
          } else {
             // done fading in the 15 items, now you can call some other function
             // here to start the next operation
             afterFade();
          }
       }, 100);
    }
    fader();
}
```

Try simplifying your click code to this:

```
$('input').click(function(){
    $('.bar').hide();
    fading();
});
```

`.hide()` is synchronous (it doesn't use the animation queue) so you can just call `fading()` right after it.

You also have to reinitialize your cntr variable on the second call to `fading()`.  In my code example above, I changed the name of the variable from `i` to `cntr` and moved it's definition and initialization into the top of the `fading()` function so it is automatically initialized on each subsequent call.

Comment: How would I queue the next action in the `fader()` function?

Comment: One way of doing it is in the code example I added to my answer.

Comment: ok yep that works fine but the problem is when I click to run the function again it doesn't execute. In other words, first click works any click after doesn't. Thanks, for your help, sorry its hard to explain what exactly I am trying to accomplish over text.

Comment: I added more to my answer to make it work on subsequent clicks.  FYI, you probably need to protect against a click while it is busy animating.